# SQL update other rows by one latest date row

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is a MS-SQL

there are many rows of data duplicated , some of them get the latest update, some not.
I want to update those old data with ones get latest info.

```
from:
    orderNum      itemID          orderTime                        desc
    7247168         101         2013-08-11 09:51:39.20             desc_101_cc
    102594          101         2012-09-26 21:17:50.44             desc_101_aaa
    631595          101         2014-03-11 19:51:29.40             desc_101_ddd
    1157428         235         2014-03-01 10:16:42.43             desc_235_8
    7212306         235         2014-03-14 11:26:51.29             desc_235_2
    100611          235         2014-03-21 20:23:43.03             desc_235_2
```

To:

```
orderNum      itemID          orderTime                        desc
7247168         101         2013-08-11 09:51:39.20             desc_101_ddd
102594          101         2012-09-26 21:17:50.44             desc_101_ddd
631595          101         2014-03-11 19:51:29.40             desc_101_ddd
1157428         235         2014-03-01 10:16:42.43             desc_235_2
7212306         235         2014-03-14 11:26:51.29             desc_235_2
100611          235         2014-03-21 20:23:43.03             desc_235_2
```

I want to use the `max(orderTime)` to get the latest edition of `desc`
then use it to update other `desc`

That means i like to use the  `orderTime` to tell which `desc` is the latest
 then update other  `desc`

**The only column needs to be updated is  the  `desc`**

Please help me with this SQL

Comment: How u decide OLD & New? by orderTime? you want to update old itemID by new itemID?Please provide more details.

Comment: Describe your problem in more detail. I doubt if anyone will read those tables to find the differences. and give the sql to create your tables.

Comment: sure that is order time  , just to update desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012, you can do this with `last_value`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             last_value("desc") over (partition by itemID order by orderTime) as lastdesc
      from table t
)
update toupdate
    set "desc" = lastdesc;
```

If you are not using SQL Server 2012, you an emulate this with a correlated subquery:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (select top 1 "desc"
              from table t2
              where t2.itemId = t.itemId
              order by orderTime desc
             ) as lastdesc
      from table t
)
update toupdate
    set "desc" = lastdesc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (won't work in SQL Server 2000 or earlier)? Don't try this on a production table; make a temporary copy table to try it.

```
;WITH MaxT AS (
    SELECT 
        itemID
        ,maxOrderTime = MAX(orderTime) 
    FROM 
        myTable
    ),
 MaxTDesc AS (
    SELECT 
        itemID
        ,desc 
    FROM 
        myTable MaxTDesc
        ,MaxT
    WHERE 
        MaxTDesc.ItemID = MaxT.ItemID 
        AND MaxTDesc.orderTime = MaxT.maxOrderTime
    )
 UPDATE 
    mt 
 SET 
    mt.desc = MaxTDesc.desc
 FROM 
    myTable mt, MaxT 
 WHERE 
    mt.itemID = MaxTDesc.itemID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...I am using `ROW_NUMBER()` to pick the latest updated record and then setting the desc columns for others

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by itemid ORDER BY ordertime desc) ROWNUM
    FROM Your_table_name    
    )
UPDATE A
SET desc = CTE.desc
FROM Your_table_name A
INNER JOIN CTE ON A.itemid = CTE.itemid
WHERE CTE.ROWNUM=1
```